# reading the value of input when clk ='1' in the mid way of clk

Tags: vhdl

I know about rising_edge(clk) and when clk'event and clk ='1'. 
i guess they detect edge.
but lets say i want to read the input when clk is high and in mid way. I guess I am able to write what I want to convey so how can we do that?
If I am not correct please explain.
thanks

Comment: I assume you want to do this in behavioral code (like a testbench) right? By halfway, do you mean the falling edge, or halfway between rising and falling edge?

Comment: Brian answered for what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a testbench, or synthesisable into real hardware?

Assuming your clock has period clk_period, declared something like

```
constant clk_period : time := 100 ns;   -- for 10 MHz
clk <= not clk after  clk_period/2;
```

you can write testbench code like

```
wait until rising_edge(clk);
wait for clk_period/4;
value <= my_input;
```

However this is not synthesisable. In real hardware you need a different approach. Most FPGAs have clock generation modules (PLLs, DLLs, DCMs) which will allow you to generate phase shifted or inverted clocks, and you can use such a block to accomplish your task. More specific suggestions would depend on the actual FPGA you are using, and whether you have any faster clocks available.

For example, given `clk` and `clk_2x` which are phase aligned (so that each clk edge is a clk_2x rising edge) you can use the falling edge of clk_2x while clk is high.

```
process(clk_2x)
begin   -- capture data
   if falling_edge(clk_2x) then
      if clk = '1' then
         temp <= data_in;
      end if;
   end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin    -- resynch to main clock domain
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      value <= temp;
   end if;
end process;
```

Alternative approaches can involve clocking the ADC from delayed, inverted or otherwise modified clocks, or using selectable delays in IOBs on the input data so that the (delayed) data is stable during the clock edge.

This is something that - without *really good* sim models of the external parts, can be quite tricky to get right in simulation, and needs thorough testing on actual hardware. I have sometimes used phase controllable clocks to external parts and mapped out the range of phases that worked before picking one phase or delay value for production.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I was asking about synthesisable into real hardware case and Yes I have clocks available of x and 2*x I can make them. I am using xc6slx9 fpga. Actually I am trying to make an adc data driver So for receiving the data I want to read at the midway as at falling edge I read the data but not able to get all the cases correct.I am using ADC161S626 adc.

Comment: can you please tell me what would be the appropriate code lines for doing that in vhdl ?